# Two even and two odd numbers appear next to each other

Tags: java

> Given an array of integer, print true if two even and two odd numbers appear next to each other in the array

I have tried to solve this using "Boolean" but not getting the expected result.

```
int[] arr={2,4,5,7,8,9,10};
int len=arr.length;
boolean bool = true;

for (int i=0; i<len-1; i++)
{
    int n=arr[i];
    int m=arr[i+1];
    if (n%2==0 && m%2==0)
    {
        for (int j=i+2; j<len-1; j++)
        {
            int a=arr[j];
            int b=arr[j+1];
            if (a%2!=0 && b%2!=0)
            {
                bool=true;
                break;
            }
            else
                bool=false;
        }
    }
    else
    {
        for (int j=i+2; j<len-1; j++)
        {
            int a=arr[j];
            int b=arr[j+1];
            if (a%2==0 && b%2==0)
            {
                bool=true;
                break;
            }
            else
                bool=false;
        }
    }
}
System.out.println("2Odd+2Even:"+bool);
```

> **Expected Result**: `2Odd+2Even:true`
>
> **Actual Result**: `2Odd+2Even:false`

Comment: You might need to rethink what `break` does in your code and if that really is what you need there and `else { bool=false; }` doesn't do you any favor either.

Comment: Read carefully through your code and ask yourself exactly what it is doing, this can help you find the issues in your design. Essentially, you need to go through the array and check all groups of 4 elements, and if  those elements groups fit your 2 even + 2 odd criteria then return true, else if you reach the end of the list without finding any then return false.

Comment: This appears to be a homework assignment, and as such does not really have a place here.
However, in the case that it is not such an assignment, you might want to look into refactoring your code to have some methods, clean naming, etc.
This will improve the likelyhood of finding your bug.

Comment: It is also unclear as to the exact nature of the assignment.  Do only sequences like `e,e,o,o` or `o,o,e,e` return true.  Or two even or two odd numbers side by side.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that your `break;` only exits the inner loop. Even after you found a match you still continue the outer loop which will set `bool` to false in the next iteration.
Without changing much you can simply add

```
if(bool){
    break;
}
```

at the end of your outer loop to leave it once you have found a match.

Answer (score 0):

Your code is a bit more complex than it needs to be; Try to keep your programs as simple as possible.
Before you start writing code think through the steps required to achieve your goal and list them out. In this case, you just need to check each group of 4 adjacent elements in array.

Something like this:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int[] a = { ... };
    System.out.println("2Odd+2Even:" + has2Odd2Even(a));
}

public static boolean has2Odd2Even(int[] a) {
    int end = a.length - 4;
    for (int i = 0; i <= end; i++) {
        if (odd(a[i])) {
            if (odd(a[i + 1]) && !odd(a[i + 2]) && !odd(a[i + 3])) {
                // 0 & 1 are odd, 2 & 3 are even
                return true;
            }
        } else if (!odd(a[i + 1]) && odd(a[i + 2]) && odd(a[i + 3])) {
            // 0 & 1 are even, 2 & 3 are odd
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}

public boolean odd(int i){
    return (i & 1) == 1;
}
```

Comment: You aren't including the case that it is 2 odd followed by 2 even though, so I think the condition (a[i]%2 != 0) && (a[i+1]%2 != 0) && (a[i+2]%2 == 0) && (a[i+3]%2 == 0) should be added as a **OR**, or else [1,3,2,4] will be false whereas it should be true :)

Comment: Updated to cover both cases

Comment: @Aviza I believe you are incorrect, please provide and explicit example. It does however need to be a static method to be used in the `main` and needs `odd(int)` defined.

Answer (score 0):

You can also do it using bit testing. I expanded the boolean constructs to make it easier to follow but they could all be combined into one if desired.  Note that the low order bit determines the number's divisibility by 2.

```java
      int[] vals = { 2, 4, 5, 7, 9, 11, 10, 14
      };
      for (int i = 0; i < vals.length - 3; i++) {
         int a = vals[i];
         int b = vals[i + 1];
         int c = vals[i + 2];
         int d = vals[i + 3];
         boolean firstTwoOdd = ((a & b) & 1) == 1;
         boolean firstTwoEven = ((a | b) & 1) == 0;
         boolean secondTwoOdd = ((c & d) & 1) == 1;
         boolean secondTwoEven = ((c | d) & 1) == 0;
         boolean oddeven = firstTwoOdd && secondTwoEven;
         boolean evenodd = firstTwoEven && secondTwoOdd;
         System.out.printf("(%d,%d,%d,%d) : %b%n",
               a,
               b,
               c,
               d,
               oddeven || evenodd);
      }
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a possible solution

```
boolean checker (int[] array) {
            if (array.length <= 3) {
                return false;
            } else {
                for (int i = 0; i < array.length - 3; i++) {
                    if (array[i] % 2 == 0 && array[i + 1] % 2 == 0) {
                        int j = i + 2;
                        if (array[j] % 2 != 0 && array[j + 1] % 2 != 0) {
                            return true;
                        }
                    } else if (array[i] % 2 != 0 && array[i + 1] % 2 != 0) {
                        int j = i + 2;
                        if (array[j] % 2 == 0 && array[j + 1] % 2 == 0) {
                            return true;
                        }
                    }
                }
                return false;
            }

        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
class Dcoder
{  
  public static void main(String args[])
  {  
    int[] arr = {2, 4, 5, 7, 8, 9, 10};
    boolean bool1 = false;
    boolean bool2 = false;
    
    for(int i = 1; i < arr.length; i++){
        
        if(arr[i-1]%2 == 0 && arr[i]%2 == 0){
            bool1 = true;
        }
        else if(arr[i-1]%2 != 0 && arr[i]%2 != 0){
            bool2 = true;
        }
    }
    System.out.println("2Odd + 2Even : " + (bool1 && bool2));
  }
}
```

Comment: Welcome to SO, please add some description to your answer and avoid putting your solution without some explanations